# Why are "df['legal_drinker'] = df.apply(majority)" and "df['legal_drinker'] = df['age'].apply(majority)" different?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to generate a new column based on the value of a certain column. I don’t know why I encountered such a problem.

```
    csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/04_Apply/Students_Alcohol_Consumption/student-mat.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_url)
    df.head()
    def majority():
    if df.age > 17:
        return True
    else:
        return False


    df['legal_drinker'] = df.apply(majority)
    df
```

Then it returned an error like this:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0bb6e6e401fe> in <module>
      4     else:
      5         return False
----> 6 df['legal_drinker'] = df.apply(majority,axis =1)
      7 df

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6879
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    294             try:
    295                 result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
--> 296                     values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
    297                 )
    298             except ValueError as err:

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction()

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result()

TypeError: majority() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

But with the following code, it works okay.

```
    def majority(age):
    if age > 17:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    df['legal_drinker'] = df['age'].apply(majority)
    df
```

Why?

Comment: From what I understand, ```df.apply(majority)``` requires a column to apply the function with.   with ```df['age'].apply(majority)```, you specified which column (i.e. ```age```).

Answer (score -1):

Different calling contexts is the answer.

#### Row on dataframe

1. Create the column with `assign()`
2. `axis=1` in `apply()` as you are applying row by row
3. The function in this context gets passed the row. Update the row and return it

#### Series

1. The function is based value in series
2. Return the required value

#### Series in dataframe

1. This is definitely the wrong use case

Conclusion - `apply()` has the same name, but its implementation and usage depends on the object on which it is acting.   [Series apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) [DataFrame apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/04_Apply/Students_Alcohol_Consumption/student-mat.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_url)
df.head()
dfc= df.copy()

# The parameter is a row, and it will be called once for each row in dataframe
def majorityrow(r):
    r.legal_drinker = r.age > 17
    return r
df.assign(legal_drinker=False).apply(majorityrow, axis=1)

# The parameter is a value, and it will be called for each item in a series

def majorityval(age):
    return age > 17

# Synonymous usages
df.assign(legal_drinker=df["age"].apply(majorityval))
df["legal_drinker"] = df["age"].apply(majorityval)
df

# Reset df
df = dfc

# The parameter is a series, it will be called once for each series in df
def majorityseries(s):
    if s.name=="legal_drinker":
        s=df.loc[:,"age"]>17
    return s

# Need to create column for the logic to work

df.assign(legal_drinker=False).apply(majorityseries)
```